# WordPress's homepage is broken

Tags: wordpress

I was running WordPress well, and when it was time to renew it, I tried to renew it with Putty

The update was not successful due to CAA forbid(?) issue. So I tried many times and the homepage didn't go in at all.

The error name was the same name as 404 Not found.

So I repeated the process that I first installed WordPress.

Then I opened my homepage and found a page called "Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page"

I just needed to renew the certificate of Let's Encrypt, but I think that the error (CAA) has led me to an irreversible situation

I made a WordPress homepage through Amazon Light Sale.

Once it started to break down, I tried this and that through Putty, the solutions I learned through googling.

Is it possible to restore my homepage? And there are a lot of posts on my WordPress homepage, so even if it's restored, will it be possible to restore many of these posts to their original state??

I was told that I can use a snapshot of Amazon's light sale, so I took a snapshot for now

I tried renewing my WordPress certificate and everything started to go bad from then on.

Answer (score 0):

I googled “update Wordpress then restore” and got several options for you. The first link, https://kinsta.com/blog/restore-wordpress-from-backup/#restore-wordpress-backup-cpanel
may do it for you.

If you didn’t make a backup before the install you will need to search for some old version of your database. Sometime automatic backups are enabled. When you reinstalled the system may have created a new database, so look to see if the old database is still there under a different name. In a real pinch you might be able to pull files off the internet way back machine.

Good luck!